# Could not parse the remainder: '[i]['fld_id']' from 'data[i]['fld_id']'

Tags: python, django

I am trying to access data from a list of dictionary to my HTML template and the following error occured while trying to access the data from the dictionary. This same error even occured initially when I tried to loop using range(len(data)) but then I created another list that stores the range. But I can't do that for a LOD.

```
Could not parse the remainder: '[i]['fld_id']' from 'data[i]['fld_id']'
```

## viwes.py

```
    data_to_print=[
                     {
                        'fld_name':i,
                        'name':randomString(10),
                        'age':randomString(2),
                        'gender':randomString(5)
                      }for i in files_in_user_folder
                  ]

    for q in range(len(data_to_print)):
        numbers.append(q)
    return render(request, 'loginpage/datapage.html',{'data':data_to_print},{'rng':numbers})
```

## template.html

```
</tr> 

      {% for i in rng %}
          <tr>
              <td> {{data[i]['fld_id']}} </td>
              <td> {{data[i]['name']}} </td>
              <td> {{data[i]['age']}} </td>
              <td> {{data[i]['gender']}} </td>
              <td> <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/{{data[i]['fld_id']}}.zip" download>Download</a></td>
          </tr>
      {% endfor %}
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not how you loop through objects in a *list* (array) in python, you don't need the index at all (`rng` is not needed). You can just loop through `data` to iterate through the **objects** in the list (in this case each object is a `person` which is a dictionary). Then access the keys of the dictionary using the dot notation (see [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/templates/#variables) to learn how to access python variables in django templates).

Do this instead:

```
{% for person in data %}
    <tr>
       <td> {{ person.fld_name }} </td>
       <td> {{ person.name }} </td>
       <td> {{ person.age }} </td>
       <td> {{ person.gender }} </td>
       <td> <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/{{ person.fld_name }}.zip" download>Download</a></td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Note: I'm using the key `fld_name` because that's what you defined in your code, as far as I can see `fld_id` isn't defined.

Answer (score 1):

in `Django template` you cannot use `[]` to parse anything, if its a `proper dictionary` use this instead

```
{{ data.i.fld_id }}
```

Comment: No, I am not able to retrieve the fld_id, name,age, gender values. its just printing an empty table

Comment: You can't access dictionary keys using variables in django templates. So this answer can't work.

Comment: How do I do it then?